# Python won't refresh URL to receive new forex ticker data

Tags: python, refresh, urllib, ticker

I am trying to save updated Forex ticker data from this website: http://forex.offers4u.biz/TickDBReadDB.php?p=EURUSD

just hit refresh to update the ticker.

when I use my little python script, it saves the text once, but if i run it again, it makes a new file with the same old data. How can I add a "cachebreaker" so that python can read the new data from the old URL?

```
import urllib2, time

filename = 'EURUSD ' + str(time.asctime()) + '.txt'

myfile = open(filename, 'w')

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://forex.offers4u.biz/TickDBReadDB.php?p=EURUSD?")

for line in page:
    myfile.write(line)

myfile.close()
page.close()
```

Comment: I ran this script and read the output file which reported an error - 'mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result '.

Comment: The webpage isn't changing at the moment... presumably because the market is closed. Is this the issue, or should we retry when the market reopens tomorrow?

Answer (score 0):

urllib2 doesn't do any caching. Are you going through a proxy?  Or the server may be caching.

Try using a Cache-Control header described [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), section 14.9

EDIT: Mind you, the most recent data on that page is from 2009.11.16 20:47:37. Are you sure it's still being actively updated?

Comment: You are right about the data on that webpage--it is not actively updating right now! 

I've contacted the admin about it, once it works I'll see if my problem still persists. Thanks for the help in the meantime!

Comment: I looked at the cache-control section you linked to me. it looks like the "no-cache" or "no store" directives will work. 

these are HTTP commands, right? how can I use them with python? should i parse the URL and insert a "no-cache" directive in there somwhere? sorry for being so clueless.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html. The last-but-one example at the bottom of the page shows an example with a request header. You'll need to do `req.add_header( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache')` or similar.